# Every Pong is Abelian

Tags: code-golf, abstract-algebra, lean

*Part of the [lean](/questions/tagged/lean) Language of the Month*

A pong* is a set \$P\$ with an operation \$+\$, that satisfies the following properties:

\$
\forall a, b \in P : (b + b) + a = a\\
\forall a, b \in P : a + (b + b) = a\\
\forall a, b, c \in P: a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c \\
\$

This makes a pong*, just a group where every element is it's own inverse.

Now most operations we know of are not pongs.  Addition is clearly not a pong.  However you should be familiar with some.  Exclusive or on booleans is a pong, since \$\mathrm{True}\oplus\mathrm{True} = \mathrm{False}\$ and \$\mathrm{False}\oplus\mathrm{False} = \mathrm{False}\$, and by extension bitwise xor on integers is also a pong.

A beginner level proof in Abstract Algebra is to show that every pong is an Abelian group.  That is given the axioms prove

\$
\forall a,b : a + b = b + a
\$

So as I thought it would be fun to tackle this problem as a beginner lean problem.  Here's a pong class:

```lean
universe u

class pong (A : Type u) extends has_add A :=
  ( add_assoc : ∀ a b c : A, (a + b) + c = a + (b + c) )
  ( left_id : ∀ a b : A, (b + b) + a = a )
  ( right_id : ∀ a b : A, a + (b + b) = a )

open pong
```

Your task is to prove the following theorem:

```
theorem add_comm (A : Type u) [pong A] : ∀ a b : A, a + b = b + a
```

As is standard now you may rename the function and golf declaration as long as the underlying type remains the same.

You may not use any of the [theorem proving sidesteps](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23938).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being the goal.

I ask that if you are experienced in Lean you give a little time for beginners to have a go at this.  Feel free to post your score below as a motivator.  You can also post a hash of your program as proof.

<sup>* A term I just made up, because saying "Group where every element is its own inverse" gets tiring real quick.</sup>

Comment: You say addition is not a pong, but over the booleans addition can be defined just as xor

Answer (score 6):

## Lean, <sup><s>115</s></sup> <sup><s>103</s></sup> 100 bytes

```
def P:=@add_assoc
def V(A)[pong A](a b:A):a+b=_:=by rw[<-right_id$a+b,<-P,P a,<-P b,left_id,left_id]
```

[Try it on Lean Web Editor!](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=universe%20u%0A%0Aclass%20pong%20%28A%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20extends%20has_add%20A%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%28%20add_assoc%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20c%20%3A%20A%2C%20%28a%20%2B%20b%29%20%2B%20c%20%3D%20a%20%2B%20%28b%20%2B%20c%29%20%29%0A%20%20%28%20left_id%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20%3A%20A%2C%20%28b%20%2B%20b%29%20%2B%20a%20%3D%20a%20%29%0A%20%20%28%20right_id%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20%3A%20A%2C%20a%20%2B%20%28b%20%2B%20b%29%20%3D%20a%20%29%0A%0Aopen%20pong%0A%0Atheorem%20add_comm%20%28A%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20%5Bpong%20A%5D%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20%3A%20A%2C%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%20b%20%2B%20a%20%3A%3D%20%CE%BB%20a%20b%2C%0Abegin%0A%20%20rw%3C-left_id%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Ba%29%2Crw%20add_assoc%2Crw%3C-add_assoc%20_%20a%2Crw%20add_assoc%20b%20a%20a%2Crw%20right_id%2Crw%20right_id%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20X%28A%3AType%20u%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3Db%2Ba%3A%3Dby%20rw%3C-left_id%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Ba%29%3Brw%20add_assoc%3Brw%3C-add_assoc%20_%20a%3Brw%20add_assoc%20b%20a%20a%3Brw%20right_id%3Brw%20right_id%20--%20138%0Adef%20Y%28A%3AType%20u%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3Db%2Ba%3A%3Dby%20rw%5B%3C-left_id%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Ba%29%2Cadd_assoc%2C%3C-add_assoc%20_%20a%2Cadd_assoc%20b%20a%20a%2Cright_id%2Cright_id%5D%20--%20126%0Adef%20Z%28A%3AType%20u%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3Db%2Ba%3A%3Dlet%20Q%3A%3D%40add_assoc%2CR%3A%3D%40right_id%20in%20by%20rw%5B%3C-left_id%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Ba%29%2CQ%2C%3C-Q%20_%20a%2CQ%20b%20a%20a%2CR%2CR%5D%20--%20122%0Adef%20Q%3A%3D%40add_assoc%0Adef%20U%28A%3AType%20u%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3Db%2Ba%3A%3Dby%20rw%5B%3C-left_id%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Ba%29%2CQ%2C%3C-Q%20_%20a%2CQ%20b%20a%20a%2Cright_id%2Cright_id%5D%20--%20120%0A%0Adef%20P%3A%3D%40add_assoc%0Adef%20V%28A%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3D_%3A%3Dby%20rw%5B%3C-right_id%24a%2Bb%2C%3C-P%2CP%20a%2C%3C-P%20b%2Cleft_id%2Cleft_id%5D%20--%20100%0A%0A--%20sanity%20check%20for%20V%0Aexample%20%28A%20%3A%20Type*%29%20%5Bpong%20A%5D%20%28a%20b%20%3A%20A%29%20%3A%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%20b%20%2B%20a%20%3A%3D%20V%20A%20a%20b%0A%23check%20V%0A%0A%2F-%0Acalc%20a%2Bb%3D%28%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28b%2Ba%29%29%2B%28a%2Bb%29%3Asymm%24left_id%20_%20_%0A...%3D%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28a%2Bb%29%29%3Aadd_assoc%20_%20_%20_%0A...%3D%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28%28%28b%2Ba%29%2Ba%29%2Bb%29%3Aby%20rw%3C-add_assoc%20_%20a%0A...%3D%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28%28b%2B%28a%2Ba%29%29%2Bb%29%3Aby%20rw%20add_assoc%20b%20a%20a%0A...%3D%28b%2Ba%29%2B%28b%2Bb%29%3Aby%20rw%20right_id%0A...%3Db%2Ba%3Aby%20rw%20right_id%0A-%2F)

-14 bytes thanks to Kyle Miller.

#### Proof outline

```
a + b
= (a + b) + ((b + a) + (b + a)) -- by right_id
= ((a + b) + (b + a)) + (b + a) -- by add_assoc
= (a + (b + (b + a))) + (b + a) -- by add_assoc
= (a + ((b + b) + a)) + (b + a) -- by add_assoc
= (a + a) + (b + a) -- by left_id
= b + a -- by left_id
```

Comment: You can shave off a few bytes with `V(A:Type u)` -> `V(A)`

Comment: Also, by allowing some metavariables while rewriting, this shaves off a few more bytes: `rw[<-right_id(a+b),<-P,P a,<-P b,left_id,left_id]`.

Comment: Oh my, you can do something even worse to shave off two bytes: `a+b=b+a` -> `a+b=_`.  This is relying on the way Lean elaborates a `def` vs a `theorem`, which is that definitions are allowed to have metavariables in their types before typechecking what comes after the `:=`.  Theorems don't allow this so that it can typecheck proofs in parallel.  (This verifies it still has the right type: `example (A : Type*) [pong A] (a b : A) : a + b = b + a := V A a b`, in addition to `#check V`.)

Answer (score 4):

## Lean, <s>141 140</s> 121 bytes

- Saved one byte thanks to Wheat Witch/Wheat Wizard
- Saved 19 bytes thanks to Kyle Miller!

```
def s:=@add_assoc
def V(A)[pong A](a b:A):a+b=b+a:=by rw<-left_id b(a+b);repeat{rw<-s};rw s;simp[right_id,s(a+b),left_id]
```

[Try it online](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=universe%20u%0A%0Aclass%20pong%20%28A%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20extends%20has_add%20A%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%28%20add_assoc%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20c%20%3A%20A%2C%20%28a%20%2B%20b%29%20%2B%20c%20%3D%20a%20%2B%20%28b%20%2B%20c%29%20%29%0A%20%20%28%20left_id%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20%3A%20A%2C%20%28b%20%2B%20b%29%20%2B%20a%20%3D%20a%20%29%0A%20%20%28%20right_id%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20a%20b%20%3A%20A%2C%20a%20%2B%20%28b%20%2B%20b%29%20%3D%20a%20%29%0A%0Aopen%20pong%0A%0Adef%20s%3A%3D%40add_assoc%0Adef%20V%28A%29%5Bpong%20A%5D%28a%20b%3AA%29%3Aa%2Bb%3Db%2Ba%3A%3Dby%20rw%3C-left_id%20b%28a%2Bb%29%3Brepeat%7Brw%3C-s%7D%3Brw%20s%3Bsimp%5Bright_id%2Cs%28a%2Bb%29%2Cleft_id%5D)

[Bubbler's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236297) is much better, but I'm just throwing my hat into the ring anyway.

Comment: Since you don't split your goal at any point you can replace all the `,`s with `;`s and get rid of the brackets to save a byte.

Comment: @WheatWitch Thanks! I was going to try that before, but Lean started erroring as soon as I replaced one comma with a semicolon. I guess it needs all of them to be replaced to work properly

Comment: 122 bytes with `def V(A)[pong A](a b:A):a+b=b+a:=by rw<-l b(a+b);repeat{rw<-s};rw[l,s,right_id,s(a+b),l]`

Comment: and 121 bytes with `def s:=@add_assoc def V(A)[pong A](a b:A):a+b=b+a:=by rw<-left_id b(a+b);repeat{rw<-s};rw s;simp[right_id,s(a+b),left_id]`

Comment: @KyleMiller Wow, thanks!